# Convert a UTF-8 character string to its integer value / UniChar (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, nsstring, unichar

I'm currently developing an Objective C program, that receives an input of UTF-8 characters as a string like "U+0008". These strings are of type NSString. Now I need to convert this string that represents this character to the corresponding UniChar (0x0008).

Do you know an elegant way of doing this?

Thanks!
Pedro

Comment: Why do you receive them as a string?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `NSString` of the form `@"U+xxxx"` where the *x* are hexadecimal digits then below are two ways to obtain the value, the "elegance" of each is in the eye of the beholder:

a) Use `NSScanner`. The method `scanString:intoString` can be used to check for the `U+`, the method `scanHexInt:` to read in the hex value, and the method `isAtEnd` to check that there is nothing left after the hex value. This method does not limit the hex number to a maximum of four digits.

b) Use `sscanf` or `strtol`. These are C-level APIs, you can obtain a C-string from your `NSString` using `UTF8String`. With `scanf` you can check for the `U+` and read in a hex number with a set maximum number of digits in one line - if that is your definition of "elegant". However checking all input is consumed requires a little thought.

There are numerous other ways to do this, anything from roll-your-own to using regular expressions (`NSRegularExpression`) to check the format and extract the 4 hex digits in one go ready for conversion to an integer.

Note if you are seeing 4 hex digits then you have a 16-bit value, more like UTF-16 than UTF-8.